# GTK3 Themes: disable differences between selected and not selected windows

Tags: themes

I typically work full screen. However, sometimes I have windows next to each other. That is because I want to see the contents of different windows at the same time. Yet, most GTK3 themes slightly dim content of a non selected window. Is there an easy way to prevent a GTK3 theme from changing the appearance of window content when a window is not selected?

Changing the appearance of title bar or window borders between unselected and selected windows is desirable. What I find undesirable is a change in appearance of the window content.

In particular for me, it concerns the Greybird theme that comes with Xubuntu 19.10 (with the standard window manger of Xubuntu). This, however, also happens with for example Adwaita or Arc, and also happens under Gnome Shell. It apparently is a feature of GTK3 themes. I do not see this happening with mousepad (GTK2) or PCmanFM (GTK2).

[image]

For nautilus, there is what can be called a bug, where the background becomes gray for the not selected window if tabs are open, but stays white for the non selected window if no tabs are open:

[image]

On top a not selected nautilus window with multiple tabs, middle a nautilus window without tabs, bottom selected nautilus window without tabs.

The difference is more subtile in a GTK3 text editor such as Gedit:

[image]

Left: not selected window, right: selected window.

Comment: Screenshot would be great here, because I don't have these problems with mine GTK theme.

Comment: And always is worth it mention which GTK theme and which DE/WM do you use.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the window manager (compositor setting?) rather than the gtk theme? At least in Kubuntu, the dimming of inactive windows is controlled by KWin.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica It happens with GTK3 themes, and I suspect it is the theme that controls it. It is not an overall dimming, it is a different rendition of different elements, including, but slightly so, text in a text editor.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. You'd need to make your own theme which doesn't handle inactive state.

Comment: @dobey as I have seen the the source code, I fear you are right. I thought it would not hurt asking it, though.

Comment: BTW, mousepad in 19.10 is gtk3. You can confirm that with `apt show mousepad` >>> `libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.2.1), libgtksourceview-3.0-1 (>= 2.91.4)`

Comment: This is strange. My Arc theme (v20190330) doesn't do these things. I wanted to achieve this effect on Debian Gnome in the past, and had to do it with [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/891/windows-blur-effects/) extension. Now I'm on Gentoo Gnome and also nothing. But on xfce? I guess there are no extensions at all here. Maybe it's only Ubuntu related?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Indeed, you are right. Mousepad, however, does not do that by default because it uses its own color scheme by default (Preferences dialog). When one sets the color sheme to "none", the theme effect shows on the text.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Arc indeed does not do that. Unfortunatelly (for me, that is), though, text in an active window is already a bit greyed compared to other themes.

Comment: @vanadium I never noticed that because I quickly set solarized dark as my color scheme! Too much white fries my eyes :(

Comment: @vanadium Ok, confirmed on Greybird and Adwaita. It really fades the text in the non-selected windows.